# Alex Martelli should get a free website when he reaches 100K reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, high-rep-users

I propose that a thread be made for volunteers to design [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli) a free website for living at SO for so long. He provides in-depth answers for all questions related to Python, and other various technologies. He's a major expert and contributor to the community but his website is terrible and he deserves better :)

Comment: It's you from a sock puppet account isn't it?

Comment: lol, nah. In fact, my fear is that he doesn't want a new website. He works for Google, so you'd think somewhere along the way he'd have gotten an offer he couldn't refuse.

Comment: Which was yesterday, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I donno... I find his web site fairly OK. No stupid flash. No ads. Few distracting visual elements. Useful content. Easy and clear navigation. Even internationalized.

Answer (score 4):

Jon Skeet didn't.

Comment: Pretty soon, we'll owe him *two*.

Comment: Nor Marc Gravell, cletus, or tvanfosson.

Comment: How about his own TLD when he reaches 500k? [www.jon.skeet](http://www.jon.skeet)

Comment: @balpha: great idea ;-) it would have to be a private tld, otherwise you'd have knock-off .skeet sites cramming advertising down your throat.

Comment: http://aww.skeet.skeet.skeet/

Comment: @snicker, pointless, but epic comment :) +1